# How to calculate the length of the linked list using constant time (O(1))

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, linked-list

I have a function to calculate the length of the list. But this is in linear time. How could I convert this to constant time (O(1))

```
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node *next;
};
```

with `Node *front;
    Node *back;`

This is function to calculate the length of the linked list

```
int length() const
{
    Node *p = front;
    int n = 0;

    while (p != nullptr)
    {
        n++;
        p = p->next;
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: The question is a bit vague. What are the restrictions? Why can't you store the length internally and update it on adding/removing nodes and the length function could just return it (making it constant) ?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis So, I need to increment when ever the node is added and decrement whenever the node is deleted?

Comment: yep :) That would be the easiest given there are no restrictions that disallow this.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis The restrictions are that I just need to modify my function

Comment: Ok you really seem confused. Can you add a size field to your list structure? If so, you can just modify the length function to return that field.

Comment: If you want the length in O(1) time, the list itself needs to keep track of its size (in a member variable) and provide a way to return it to you. You cannot calculate it on the fly in less than O(n) time.

Comment: @JesperJuhl actually with some trickery he could, assume he never inserts data by Node* but by T, he COULD allocate the Node* in continuous memory  and then length is back - front / sizeof(*), but that being said, it beats the whole purpouse of a list. The question is simply vague.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Sure. If you basically use a vector rather than a list you have other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A theoretical way to do this **if** you are allowed to change the list structure with new fields could go like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct Node
{
    T data;
    Node* next;
};

template<typename Node>
struct List
{
    // I assume there is a thingy that initializes these, otherwise bad things will happen
    Node *front;
    Node *back;
    int length;
    
    void add(Node* node) // No idea what the signature is
    {
        // I am not gonna do the adding for you
        
        // If everything went fine increase the length
        length += 1;
    }
    
    void remove(Node* node) // Again, no idea of the signature
    {
        // Again, not gonna do the removal
        
        // If everything went fine decrease the length
        length -= 1;
    }
    
    int get_length() const
    {
        return length;
    }
};
```

Comment: I am totally confused can you please explain more.

Comment: What exactly confuses you in this snippet? Do you already have addition and removal functions for your list? If so, just increase the length on addition and removal. If you don't have them, then well,.... post a link to the homework:D

Comment: @tienlee I think you've confused everyone by asking an impossible question. There is no way to convert your length function to O(1) if the only tthing you are allowed to modify is the length function. How can you **count** something which has length N in O(1) time, it makes no sense. The only option is to not count the length, and instead keep track of the length as you add or remove items from your list. That is what this answer is showing. But it seems to contradict your statement that 'The restrictions are that I just need to modify my function' so I'm not sure if it's the answer or not.

Comment: @john thanks for the nice explanation, I did not have the patience to write this:)

Comment: @john The instructions given to me are function
  
    *     make modifications so that this
    *     operation becomes constant time (O(1)).
    *
    *   This task is different from most others in that most of
    *       the "real" work you do to make this work
    * in O(1) time will be in _other_ functions which affect
    * the length of lists.

Comment: @tienlee Well, that is just what my snippet shows :) you change other functions that append and remove the nodes, to calculate the length (the real work).

Comment: @tienlee Well that is saying exactly what the answer above shows. The *other* functions that change the length of the list must be modified so that you keep track of the length at all times, and you don't have to calculate it 'on the fly'. So this answer is the answer you need.

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @tienlee The issue is probably you started with a `Node` struct, and didn't see beyond that.  You don't really have a linked list class, as the answer illustrates.  You need to create that class first, then the answer makes sense.  Otherwise, you have to use a global `count` variable to keep track, and you know that using `global` variables is not recommended.